# Best way to save external systems credentials

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, authentication

I'm working with an app that provides basic username and password authentication to access their API. Specific access to this api would be on an user-by-user basis and their rights in the external application. What is the best way to store these external credentials, and what is the best say to pass them back to the app?

I'm currently working with Node.js using Express, and MySQL.

I'm looking for specific technologies to possibly use? I'm a bit new, and was trying to hash them and save them to the database, but then I don't know how to send it back to the application...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Definitely *don't* try to roll your own security, invest in an a proper, industry tried & tested, user authentication service like:

- [Okta](https://www.okta.com)
- [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/)
- [Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/active-directory-b2c/)
- [Auth0](https://auth0.com)

And the likes, you won't regret it.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing the password to store it in the database is usually the least you should do to keep this information safe. It is necessary however that the way you hash it is also an approved and secure way, so not every hashing algorithm is useful here. There are a lot of ways to do this, you should always rely on something approved, maybe even something open source so that a community can check wether its really secure or not. Usually there are security packages for every operating system that you can use that implement those things properly, you should never try to code your own stuff here in my opinion. You could check for sha-256 or sha-512 implementations for example, just to give you well known and approved algorithms that I assume often do the job.

The question I'm asking myself is why you would want to send the information back to the frontend because in most cases this should not be necessary. Once hashed in the database you should never be able to retrieve the original password anyway. If you want to verify if a user entered a correct password, you can easily check that fully on the backend side. This can be done by sending the credentials entered in the frontend to the backend (this is a security problem already which is why you should use something like ssl), then hash the password with the exact same algorithm you use to hash passwords initially and compare this hash with the hash that was saved in the database for the given user. This is a simple equals check that tells you if the credentials were correct or not and therefore telling you if the login should be successful or not. Then there is no way to send the information bsck to the frontend.

Also I'd advise to use a random string value for every new password and combine it with the password before the hashing function to create a unique string. I think this is referred to as a *salt* value. This way two passwords won't have the same value in the database even if they are actually the same password, which makes it more secure. When you use a salt value you have to save it as plain text in the database with the rest of the indormation though so you can use it for the equal check again later. In this case you can load the salt value of the user and combine it with an entered password again, hash it with your algorithm and check if the entered and saved hashes are equal. Both hashes should only be equal if they were generated with the same salt, password and hashing algorithm.

There is a lot more that you can do to secure this stuff, this is just a basic example of how you could achieve a relative secure login mechanism with relatively low amount of effort. It always depends on what you are trying to do, if it's a simple home stuff or maybe something for a big company and so on. If it affects a high amount of users with information that needs to be extremely secure I would recommend to use professional toolsets or services ehich specialize in exactly those kind of things.

### Edit

#### nodejs crypto implementation

For the hashing functionality you can checkout nodejs' internal [crypto service](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) that brings a ton of functionality with it. Here's some code to give you an example of how creating a hash with a salt can look like.

```
var sha512 = function (password, salt) {
    // create hmac instance with algorithm and salt
    var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', salt);
    // here comes the password that you want to hash
    hash.update(password);
    // get the hashed value 
    var value = hash.digest('hex');
    // keep the salt for future references
    return {
        salt: salt,
        passwordHash: value
    };
};
```

#### passport authentication library

If you want to implement a real authentication you can have a look into Jared Hansons [passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) library. It helps you to implement all the stuff that is usually quite tricky like keeping the user logged in, making sure certain http requests are only possible if the user is logged in, keeping track of the user state or sending an authentication token to the frontend. It's still tricky to begin with, but it is still way easier than doing this on your own. Also he brings an insane amount of so called *strategies* with it that you can install and use, for example for oauth authentication with facebook, google, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this information! This is what my approach was going to be, but i'm getting stuck when trying to retrieve the hashed password and trying to pass it to the application for authentication. Any thoughts?

Comment: And to your question, I don’t want to send the password to the front end, but to the API for authorization

Comment: Just to be clear, the hashing is made on server side. You send a password to a backend route, there you execute a function like the one in my answer, and then you either safe it in the database or you compare it with an existing one from the database. If you're stuck with how to send the password to the backend, I definitely recommend looking into passports local strategy, there are some examples on how to achieve this. Or is it something where you're stuck at?

Comment: I’m stuck at something else. I want a user to essentially only be required to enter their passwords one time only for the external system. I do know how to hash the password and save it to the database, and how to use this password during that session. I also know how to compare a users entry on the client side and compare it to the hashed password for authentication to my application.  What I don’t know, is how to use the hashed password after it has been saved to the database to authenticate with the external application for future sessions.